# MS Access DLookup Bound textbox formatting

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a basic form with some controls on it.

When I select a value in a combobox it fires a changed event.  The changed event contains a Dlookup as follows

```
Me.Description = DLookup("[Description]", "[Lookup_Endorsements]", "[Code]= '" & Me.End_No & "'")
```

This works and populates the *bound textbox* "Me.Description".  However it doesn't retain the formatting.  If I set the value in an UnBound textbox it retains the formatting correctly.

For example,

Lets say the text is like this...

"The text is some sentences and then some returns with

i) an item here

ii) another here

then another sentence"

In a bound textbox the data return from DLookup is

"The text is some sentences and then some returns with i) an item here
ii) another here then another sentence"

It doesn't retain the original formatting.  I have check the field in both the source and destination tables and they are like for like.

Any help much appreciated as I'm new to this sort of stuff in Access.

Comment: Make it a multi line box  Other - Enter Key Behaviour

Comment: Thanks, but is already set to a multiline with Enter Key behaviour as "New line in field"